# Node 'riak@192.168.1.218' not responding to pings

Tags: ubuntu, riak

I have no idea what happend with the system, but suddenly when I issue `riak start` it doesn't start anymore. I get this output.

And if I issue riak console, I get no response for pings.
I don't know what to do, so please advise how to put the system back online.

```
root@aliceubuntu:/home/alice# riak start
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 1024; 4096 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable
WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.
root@aliceubuntu:/home/alice# riak console
Node 'riak@192.168.1.218' not responding to pings.
config is OK
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 1024; 4096 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
Exec: /usr/lib/riak/erts-5.9.1/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib/riak/releases/1.4.1/riak              -config /etc/riak/app.config             -pa /usr/lib/riak/lib/basho-patches             -args_file /etc/riak/vm.args -- console
Root: /usr/lib/riak
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true]

/usr/lib/riak/lib/os_mon-2.2.9/priv/bin/memsup: Erlang has closed.
                                                                   Erlang has closed
    {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,riak_core,{bad_return,{{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{function_clause,[{orddict,fetch,['riak@192.168.1.218',[]],[{file,[111,114,100,100,105,99,116,46,101,114,108]},{line,72}]},{riak_core_capability,renegotiate_capabilities,1,[{file,[115,114,99,47,114,105,97,107,95,99,111,114,101,95,99,97,112,97,98,105,108,105,116,121,46,101,114,108]},{line,416}]},{riak_core_capability,handle_call,3,[{file,[115,114,99,47,114,105,97,107,95,99,111,114,101,95,99,97,112,97,98,105,108,105,116,121,46,101,114,108]},{line,202}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,[103,101,110,95,115,101,114,118,101,114,46,101,114,108]},{line,588}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,[112,114,111,99,95,108,105,98,46,101,114,108]},{line,227}]}]},{gen_server,call,[riak_core_capability,{register,{riak_core,vnode_routing},{capability,[proxy,legacy],legacy,{riak_core,legacy_vnode_routing,[{true,legacy},{false,proxy}]}}},infinity]}}}}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: /var/log/riak/erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,riak_core,{bad_return,{{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{function_clause,[{orddict,fetch,['riak@192.168.1.218',[]
root@aliceubuntu:/home/alice#
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to paste this somewhere else?

Comment: @BradLarson sorry I was on a phone call

Comment: What version of Riak are you running? Is this just happening on the one node, or others in the cluster too?

Comment: riak 1.4 I have one single VM, and on the same VM probably I have two nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the whole process here is that

- for some reason IP was changed on the machine riak
- the IP was hard-coded in /etc/riak/vm.args and /etc/riak/app.config

the process to revive is the following:

- edit and set the new IPs in the above files
- `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/riak/ring/* # delete the riak ring`
- restart the machine or do the next steps:
- `riak-admin cluster force-replace riak@127.0.0.1 riak@"`hostname -i`" # replace the name`
- `riak start # start the node`

This topic is also linked to this problem: [Riak node no longer working after changing IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859906/riak-node-no-longer-working-after-changing-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to initiate a new riak node is simply run riak console on your riak container bash.

```
1. If riak is a container in your docker then follow this procedure (MAC)
a. get riak image id <docker ps --all>
b. run bash command <docker exec -it "riak-container-id" bash>
c. run <riak console> this initiates a new riak node console
d. open another terminal and run <riak-shell>
e. run command<connect use your node created at step c> it will look like 
riak@10.1.0.216
```

there you go.