# riak won't start after changing nodename

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, host, riak

I've just installed riak on my virtual machine (Ubuntu 14.04).
The problem is that when I've edited  `/etc/riak/riak.conf` from:

> nodename = riak@127.0.0.1

to

> nodename = riak@10.20.0.110

which is ip of my virtual machine, service won't start. I got following error.

> root@ubuntu-amd64:/home/ubuntu# riak console
>
> config is OK
>   -config /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/app.2015.07.20.09.57.02.config -args_file /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2015.07.20.09.57.02.args -vm_args /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2015.07.20.09.57.02.args
>   Exec:  /usr/lib/riak/erts-5.10.3/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib/riak/releases/2.1.0/riak               -config /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/app.2015.07.20.09.57.02.config -args_file /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2015.07.20.09.57.02.args -vm_args /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2015.07.20.09.57.02.args              -pa /usr/lib/riak/lib/basho-patches -- console
>   Root: /usr/lib/riak
>   Erlang R16B02_basho8 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:1:1] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true] [frame-pointer]
>
> [os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
>   [os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed
>   {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,riak_core,{bad_return,{{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{function_clause,[{orddict,fetch,[riak@localhost,[]],[{file,\"orddict.erl\"},{line,72}]},{riak_core_capability,renegotiate_capabilities,1,[{file,\"src/riak_core_capability.erl\"},{line,441}]},{riak_core_capability,handle_call,3,[{file,\"src/riak_core_capability.erl\"},{line,213}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,585}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,239}]}]},{gen_server,call,[riak_core_capability,{register,{riak_core,vnode_routing},{capability,[proxy,legacy],legacy,{riak_core,legacy_vnode_routing,[{true,legacy},{false,proxy}]}}},infinity]}}}}}}"}
>
> Crash dump was written to: /var/log/riak/erl_crash.dump
>   Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,riak_core,{bad_return,{{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{function_clause,[{orddict,fetch,[riak@localhost,[]],[{fi

I've noticed that nodename variable is very sensitive, it won't work even with such configuration:

> nodename = riak@localhost

Of course I've changed

```
listener.http.internal = 10.20.0.110:8098
listener.protobuf.internal = 10.20.0.110:8087
```

as well.

[/var/log/riak/erl_crash.dump](http://wklej.org/id/1759894/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772899/node-riak192-168-1-218-not-responding-to-pings).

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/riak/ring/* # delete the riak ring
```